# 'Random' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Random' and 'System.Random' where is my mistake?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

The script is :

```
public class  : MonoBehaviour
{
    
public GameObject prefabEnemy;

    public Vector2 limitMin;
    public Vector2 limitMax;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CreateEnemy());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    IEnumerator CreateEnemy()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            float r = Random.Range(limitMin.x, limitMax.x);
            Vector2 creatingPoint = new Vector2(r, limitMin.y);

            Instantiate(prefabEnemy, creatingPoint, Quaternion.identity);

            float creatingTime = Random.Range(0.5f, 3.0f);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(creatingTime);
        }
    }
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(limitMin, limitMax);
    }
}
```

The error is :

```
Assets\Scenes\EnemyCreate.cs(29,23): error CS0104: 'Random' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Random' and 'System.Random'
```

Comment: `= Random.Range`->`= UnityEngine.Random.Range`. Or remove the `using System;`.

Comment: You can also say `using Random = UnityEngine.Random;`, or alias it to any other name (for example:  `using UnityRandom = UnityEngine.Random;`)

Answer (score 2):

`Random` is used in 2 different libraries, on `System` and also in `UnityEngine`, so you must specify which one are you trying to use.

To achieve that, you can specify it typing:

```
using UnityEngine;
```

or

```
using System;
```

On the top of your script.
You can also avoid the "using" if you type directly which random is referencing, like:

```
float r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(limitMin.x, limitMax.x);
```

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are having on top of your source file both:
using System;
and
using UnityEngine;

These both have Random class defined so you get the error.
Try using:

```
float r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(limitMin.x, limitMax.x);
```

Cheers!

Comment: float r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(limitMin.x, limitMax.x); I edited this but, still "error CS0138: A 'using namespace' directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'Random' is a type not a namespace. Consider a 'using static' directive instead"